# How can I get a discontiguous "block" of data from an eigen matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

Suppose I wanted to apply some generic operation a matrix consisting of some subset of its values that are not necessarily contiguous. How can I do this?

If the values were contiguous I would simply use the [`Eigen::block`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a1dbaa2fc7b809720407130f48dfacf8f) operation, but what if they are not?

One application might be that I have an eigen matrix of positive integers:

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, 4, 1> mat;
mat << 4, 1, 2, 8;
```

And I wanted to return the 0th, 2nd and 3rd values. If they were contiguous (0th, 1st and 2nd) I could simply use the `block` operation on this matrix, but what do I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

How about rearranging the elements to *make* them contiguous?

```
1 0 0 0     4     4
0 0 1 0  x  1  =  2
0 0 0 1     2     8
0 0 0 0     8     0
```

Comment: Thanks :) This is performance critical code though so I'm reluctant to use this solution because of the O(N^2) memory footprint. Can this be achieved without a temporary matrix?

Comment: @quant: I don't know enough about `eigen` to say that it doesn't provide an elegant solution, but it looks to me as if you have to choose between simplicity and performance.

Comment: @quant You can consider using a [SparseMatrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html).